# How to retrieve DB connection using DataSource without JNDI?

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi

We want our own db connection configuration instead of using JNDI, but in the meantime, we also want to use DataSource instead of using DriverManager, how to do so?

Comment: have a look at [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [commons dbcp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) connection poolers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use a connection pool library like [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or [commons dbcp](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

C3P0

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass( "org.postgresql.Driver" ); //loads the jdbc driver            
cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb" );
cpds.setUser("dbuser");                                  
cpds.setPassword("dbpassword");

Connection connection = cpds.getConnection();
```

DBCP

```
BasicDataSource ds= new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testdb");
ds.setUsername("dbuser");
ds.setPassword("dbpassword");

Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

```
BasicDataSource ds= new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@dburl:port:sid");
ds.setUsername("uname");
ds.setPassword("pass");
```